# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web". Relative references must start with either "/", "./"

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, client-side-scripting

I am trying to use Azure applicationinsights for client side javascript so imported following module in html as follows

```
<script type="module" >
    import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web'
    const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
        connectionString : '...............'
      /* ...Other Configuration Options... */
    } });
    appInsights.loadAppInsights();
    appInsights.trackPageView(); // Manually call trackPageView to establish the current user/session/pageview  
</script>
```

Comment: does anybody able to figure out this issue?